# Getting org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials exception Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Hi I am trying to so sprig authentication manually and wants to save the user details for spring security. But i am getting this exception in the code given below at line

```
Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);
```

Exception -

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

Service method -

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authManager;

@Override
public Boolean authenticateUser(User user) {
    String password = Utils.generateOtp(6).toString();
    user.setPassword(password);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How you are authenticating the user like against jdbc or memory?
Please check is there any password encrypted?

Comment: I am using implementation of org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService; to load use details from database